# PostgreSQL writes stdout messages to stderr

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm building a Python (PyQt) application which deals with bulk loads to a PostgreSQL 9.4 database which requires the use of `psql` commands within a process. The application captures both stdout and stderr and displays them differently, but it appears that PostgreSQL sends NOTICE and other messages to stderr, while I would expect them to appear on stdout since they aren't critical and aren't errors. This makes it extremely difficult to correctly pull out messages which I care about and ones I don't.

Is there a config setting I'm missing which properly separates the two, or am I stuck with this?

This Q&A from 17 years ago is little help: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/199812310042.TAA23174@candle.pha.pa.us

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL is this for? Because [current source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/psql/common.c#L117) indicates that *NOTICE*s go to `stderr`. Query output should go to `stdout`. Also: What is the special case that requires bulk loading to use `psql`?

Comment: v9.4. We have lots of geospatial tables which need to be loaded from ESRI FileGDBs (using `ogr2ogr`), rasters (using `raster2pgsql`) or  from CSV (using `\copy`), then manipulated to dump them into existing tables. This proved too difficult or impossible to do in psycopg2 or using the QSqlDatabase/QSqlQuery modules.